How to recrystalize 3,5 dimethoxy aniline after years of oxidation
I want to purify a quantity of 3,5 dimethoxyaniline so i can use it in a N-formylation reaction. The reagent has gained a black color from years of oxidation. Which solvent should i use for the recrystalization ?

I cannot find a specific reference to the recrystallisation of this, but I think MeOH would be a good solvent to try.

Your are sure neither your group (or another in the department), nor the uni's library has a copy of Perrin/Armarego's Purification of Laboratory Chemicals around?  If it doesn't describe the compound in question, break it down (e.g., as a methoxyaniline, or anisidine) and search this instead.  E.g., for p-anisidine, the book recommends either water, or aq. EtOH (p.86 in the third edition by 1988). So try the adjustable blend of EtOH/water.

It probably won't be directly useful in the formylation reaction, but you may also want to consider re-purifying the aniline as the hydrochloride salt, which might be easier to re-crystallize (maybe), and which will almost certainly be more resistant to further oxidation/degradation if you store the material again for years and years.

I tried to crystallize my reagent with EtOH but what but all I got was some black mud, which after I tested it with TLC ,produced two spots. What I ended up doing was a filtration with silica in column. I managed to gather a cleaner aniline.
